# Set up a Raspberry Pi 3B+ to boot up and run a Python script immediately

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

Initial conditions: Raspberry Pi 3B running on latest Raspbian OS
Application: Python script recording audio through a USB Microphone and lighting up LEDS on the GPIOs ports.
Currently working: We need to wait for the Raspberry Pi OS fully up and running and then we launch the Python script from the command line.
What we need: As soon as we power up the Raspberry, we would like the unit to boot up and run our Python script directly without any extra UI input.

Comment: Duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few ways, see [here](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/). One of the ways would be to add the program to be run at startup to the init.d directory using the following lines:

```
sudo cp /home/pi/sample.py /etc/init.d/
```

Move to the init directory and open the sample script

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo nano sample.py
```

Comment: Thanks! We have tried several methods and at the moment, using crontab plus a bash file seems to run our script.fy upon restart. How do we know? We can see the CPU load going to 25% in a 3B+ or 100% on a Pi Z W.  However, the script doesnt work and doesnt print any of the messages we have inside the code to know where we are running. We even added a log functionality into a txt file that it has been tested but doesnt save anything when we run the script upon boot-up. In the end, we need to KILL the process manually as we dont know what is going on.

Any ideas or help?

Comment: are you redirecting the print statements to a file using > or have you opened a file in your python script and wrote over there?

Comment: We are using both and we made to work finally! it is just super slow booting up.

Comment: could you post your detailed solution as answer here, so that others can benefit.